# CiviCRM Contribution Page Theme

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, theme

I was wondering if anyone had suggests on great themes that I could purchase or are free for the public facing CiviCRM contribution pages? We would like to to be very responsive (Mobile friendly) and maybe incorporate Bootstrap.

Any ideas or suggestions are helpful. Thanks

[image]

Comment: what CMS are you using?

Comment: Whoops! Should have mention that I'm using Drupal.

Comment: Some of the issues you are experiencing were also resolved in the most recent version of shoreditch. You can also prevent the shoreditch css from loading on public facing pages.

Comment: @themak Do you know how you would prevent the Shoreditch css from loading on public pages?

Comment: I am not really sure how with drupal - with wordpress - @christianwach made it a apart of his CiviCRM admin utilities plugin. you can restrict civicrm-custom.css and bootstrap.css from loading on public facing pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a drupal theme Civi Bartik Public: https://github.com/CiviCooP/civi_bartik_public

You can configure the colors in the drupal admin. Unfortunately I dont have screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Since contribution pages are front end drupal pages you can use bootstrap theme since its very responsive or amnesty have customized drupal [theme](https://github.com/amnesty/ai-theme-civicrm) compatible for CiviCRM

Comment: I have thought about that but there is some issues with the form labels being blocked by the input fields. See picture above

Comment: which 'that' are you referring to above? The 'amnesty' theme? Bootstrap?

Comment: Using the Bootstrap theme